# Merging jQuery AJAX requests for Zend Framework

Tags: php, ajax, zend-framework, jquery

I have a Zend Framework based web application which is generating 3 separate AJAX requests to the server in addition to the main page request. This is causing a significant performance hit to the web server.

I would like to try and mitigate this by combining all 3 AJAX requests into a single request that can be received by my Zend Framework application and processed by the action stack as 3 separate requests.

Any suggestions for tools/techniques and pitfalls would be welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the top of my head:

- build a request stack or queue (js array)
- send requests to request stack instead of firing off an ajax request
- send an ajax request containing the request stack array
- loop through the array server side and follow instructions

That would be something like a mini job stack/queue for ajax requests.

Comment: I am using a Zend Framework view helper to keep a count of the number of expected AJAX requests.  Where the code previously called a $.GET or $.POST in jQuery, I am now calling my own jQuery plugin which keeps each of the requests in stack (js array).  Once the number of requests in the stack matches the number specified in the view helper, I fire a single request to my Zend Framework Ajax controller which parses each request in turn.  The problem now is that several of these AJAX calls require data to be sent back.  What is the best way to pass the matching data to the relevant request?

Comment: Again you should send them back bundled and marked in an array and your plugin then sorts through the array and routes the responses further. Your plugin basically works like a request router. So every request you send to the plugin gets an ID and in the big response array you can find the sub-response by ID and do with it what's needed.

Answer (score 0):

I took Markus' advice and created 2 jQuery plugins, one for queuing the requests and one for posting them.

The Zend Framework application receives the requests and iterates through each one adding any return data to a universal response object which is JSON encoded and returned to the client.

```
var count = 0;
var requests = new Array();

// Add AJAX requests to the queue
(function($){$.fn.addAjaxRequest=function(callback, ajaxArgs, initialArgs) {
        requests[count] = [callback, ajaxArgs, initialArgs];
        count++;
    }
})
(jQuery);

// Send the queued AJAX requests to MVC
(function($){$.fn.postAjaxRequests=function(host) {
        var response = null;
        var url = 'http://' + host + '/ajax/process-ajax-requests';
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: url,
            dataType: 'json',
            async: false,
            data : ({data : requests}),
            success: function(data) {
                response = data;
            }
        });
        return response;
    }
})
(jQuery);
```